# Did each two of the Trimurti stop working while the third works?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma

Did each two of the Trimurti stop working while the third person of the Trimurti works?

I.e: when Brahma creates, Vishnu and Shiva stop working (preservation/destruction), when Vishnu preservates, Brahma and Shiva stop working (creation/destruction)... And so on?

Comment: creation, preservation, and destruction happen continuously at all times... if you observe your thoughts also they are created first, preserved for a certain amount of time, and are then destroyed... the world is continuously going through transformation...

Comment: @Tezz could you include your ideas in an answer post, supporting your answer with evidences from scriptures?

Answer (score 1):

1. Śiva is often translated as the destroyer, this is a linguistic error during translation. Due to the lack of Spiritual Vocabulary in English, we are having such a misnomer. Destruction means to damage or eliminates the composition of an object, resulting in remnants that usually get dispersed; hence destruction always has a byproduct or a leftover. This is very similar to the conservation of Quantum Information. Say an apple is destroyed beyond visible recognition; whatever information that consists of, the quantum properties that make up the apple are never destroyed. Hence, the word “destroyer” creates a vague interpretation of an attacker or an assailant. The concept of Śiva doesn't go around attaching the world like the villains in Marvel/DC Movies. In fact, Śiva is Pralaya Karaka. In the case of Pralaya (the closest word is dissolution), the object merges into the source as one (the concept of laya). This is done in 3 ways [(complete article on laya)](http://sanatanadhara.com/laya-dissolution/): Swalpakalika Laya, Aatyantica Laya, pra:laya / mahapra:laya. At the highest level, the throbbing within the Singularity just subsides. (Content references can be found in Swami Venkatesananda's Vasista Yogam, 1993, and TED-Ed Quantum Information. 2019)
2. The notion that creation >> preservation >> dissolution is a linear event is because we are preserving it through our intellect which operates on sensory data. The wisdom shared by the Sages (Rishis) of Sanatana Culture says otherwise. Our notion of time is linear just because it's inaccessible to us at the present movement. At one level time in which these 3 occurrences are perpetual, meaning they are happening in a cyclic loop non-stop aross infinite creations and their dissolution. ~ Sources can be found in Vasista Yogam & Devi Bhagavatam. Following is the Vedic view on time and dissolution and the role of Vishnu and Brahma in line with  Śiva.

**TIME in Vedic View**: Let’s explore two unique titles, first is trikāgnikālāya meaning the 3 fires which blaze at all times (garhapatya, ahavaniya, and agnihotra). Time is always burning or is exhaustive, meaning it doesn’t stop, and trik+āgni+kālāya also depicts the three dimensions of time, which are the memory of the past, the present moment at hand, and the upcoming imaginative future. One might think of past and future as linear events and so are non-existential, but we will address this soon. The second title is kālāgnirudrāya (कालाग्निरुद्र) meaning fire that devours time, why because Rudra itself is TIME, hence the title Kālāya Namaha“कालाय नमः” TA10.18 (I bow to you oh time) and this finally landed in Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad wherein it says “अन्त:काले सञ्चुकोच”SU3.2 meaning He dissolves all beings into Him at end of time. One might consider both past and future to be non-existential, however, though non-accessible in this dimension, but the same Upaniṣhad says “संयोगनिमित्तहेतुः त्रिकालात् परः अकलः अपि दृष्टः”SU6.5 meaning when one beheld in witness of Rudra, know He is the cause and the beginning of all causes; beyond the past, present and the future and he is not a part of it. Śrī Kṛṣṇa says to Yudhishthira in Mahābhāratam Anushasnika parvam 161.11 that Rudra is the past, the present, and the future, the exact statement was repeated by Rśi Vyāsa in Drona Parva 202. Maharśi Vaśiṣṭha’s Ramayana speaks extensively on the accessibility of time through dimensions beyond the current, and how Devi Sarasvatī takes her devotee across time to make her witness the past, present and future unfold at the same instance. This is why Maharśi Vaśiṣṭha says “only concepts like Shiva go beyond time”. [(Source link for detailed readers)](http://namahshivaya.net/mahakal-time-agni/)

**General consenses:** In creation, everything from the largest to the tiniest aspect is cyclic (perpetual) in nature and each cycle has both manifestation and dissolution. Hence, in Nirvana Shatakam, Śrī Śankaracharya addresses Śiva as “Cidanandata Rupa” (Cit:Anandat:Rūpa) – meaning, the essence of Ananda (Supreme bliss) in Cit (Supreme Infinite Consciousness). Similarly, the Kśhetra/temple in South India “Chitambaram”, where “Cit” means Supreme Consciousness and “Ambaram” to wear as a garment. On the other hand, Viṣṇu is Jagannatha (Jagat+Natha), meaning He is the only destiny (Natha) to be reached in Jagat. As Jagadguru Shri Chandrasekharendra Sarasvatī said “Sarvam Viṣṇu:mayam jagat”, meaning when one realizes that Jagat itself is Viṣṇu, then the one realizing this ceases to exist as a Jīva and becomes Ekam (Singularity); this state of ekam is Śivam (Supreme state of Bliss), hence “Sarvam Viṣṇu:mayam jagath: Śivam”. That is why the hymn from Nārāyaṇa Sukta (Mahanarayana Upaniṣhad) of Yajur Veda says one should meditate upon Viṣṇu (the all-pervasiveness) as the means of realizing the self, which is Nārāyaṇa. Since Viṣṇu is the only thing to achieve, a Ḍharma:patni (wife) addresses her husband as Pati or Natha or Swami. In the ceremony of Vivaha (weddings) the groom is treated as Viṣṇu and the bride is treated as Lakṣmī. This very Viśvām is nothing but Viṣṇu. To depict this, we have the story of Kṣīrāsagara manthana – in which the cosmic ocean was churned and both prosperity (Lakṣmī) and anti-creation (Halāhala) emerged. Whereas Lakṣmī went to the all-pervasive preserver Viṣṇu as his consort, the Halāhala was devoured by PāramaŚiva. Hence the profound quote, **“we grow as we dissolve”** (no reference found for this quote). So there is growth in dissolution, there is wisdom in aging as the fruit gets sweeter the more it ripes. [(source link on the dissolution)](http://namahshivaya.net/is-siva-a-destroyer/)

**Yoga and Vedantic View (Darshana)**: The Vedāntic and Yogic Darshana state that, out of infinite possibilities of Brahman arises a throbbing or vibration (Śakti), the concept of creation and its preservation emerges from this as a thought, this concept is titled Vishnu (Viṣṇu) – meaning that which is “all-pervasive” or that which “encompasses everything”. Hence Viṣṇu is an aspect of Cit Śakti (cit:śakti) and so the entirety of creation becomes Viśvām. In Sanskrit, “Viś” or “Viśta” means that which enters or permeates, hence the title Viṣṇu or ŚipiViṣṭa. Sri Aurobindo famously calls Viṣṇu the space or canvas in which all inhabitants flourish, while Śiva is the auspiciousness that is a natural occurrence untouched by the temporary realities created by Prakṛti. Shiva is Su:Mangalam, and the force or innate indweller of all is Rudra. In the Vedas, it is Prajapathi who is the instigator of creation through the process called Yajñá. He is the owner and the sponsor of the Yajñá, the Brahmana section of Vedas is full of his exploits in instigating creation in diverse forms hence Śakti (resonance) is his daughter. Knowing ṛta and bringing out the amṛta is Satyam – knowing this, realizing this, is Sundaram (the ever blissful joy). Hence “Satyam Śivam Sundaram”. Let us elaborate with a question, that which pervades everything – is it ominous or auspicious? It is auspicious, this concept is called Śiva, and the encompassing nature is called Viṣṇu, the force that propels creation is Rudra, the vibration is called Śakti, the mind and the ruler of the individual’s psychology is Indra, the life-force is Vayu, the brilliance is Surya, the transmutation is Agni, speech is Sarasvatī AB3.1.2 and Vāk which in return is also Agni as He is the Priest(Hotr), and variation/flavor/sweetness of Rudra is the Immortal Soma. Now, let us elaborate on each aspect of this summary in detail, with its origin in the Vedas. [(Source link for detailed readers)](https://wordpress.com/view/namahshivaya.net)

**Puráńic View & Historical View:** The Viṣṇu of the Puráńas is an aggregated personification of Śakti, Indra, Brahmā and Surya (including many other Vedic Solar Deities called Ādityas), whereas Śiva, thought to be associated with Rudra, Soma, Agni, Varuna, Mitra, Vayu, and Maruts in the Vedic realm, remains a total enigma. Across the literature, we see various sages, Ṛṣi, Asuras, Devatas, Avataras, and many prominent personalities establishing Liṅgas. Historical evidence like the Vrātya seals and Liṅga found in the Indus Valley have been unearthed across diverse lands. In this research, let us not take the historic approach; rather, focus on the literary indications and link them across various schools (Vedic Śākhās).

**Conclusion:** Confining the aspect of Śiva to just a single concept is impossible; in short, the essence (tatva) of Śiva is a paradox – we will see that soon. Śiva means “bliss”, “auspicious”, “foremost”, “un-manifested”, “raw”, “that which is not”; we will cover each of these aspects one by one with references, so the definition of Śiva/Rudra will evolve in this discussion. Śrī Śankaracharya, in Nirvana Shatakam, addresses Śiva as cit:ānanda:rūpa – meaning the essence of ānanda (supreme bliss) in Cit (Supreme Infinite Consciousness). If Śiva is cit:ānanda then His forever companion Uma is cit:śakti. If Śiva is a calm ocean, then Śakti is a ripple in that calm ocean. This ripple emerges from that ocean and then fades back into the same ocean. So, creation is a ripple, and all of Prakṛti is a resonance. Unlike sukha (happiness), which has a polar opposite called dukha (sadness), ānanda has no polar opposite, meaning it is a forever-state devoid of any polarity, irrespective of cit:Śakti being in action or repose (rest). Hence Śiva says to Uma: “I am the sea and you the wave, You are Prakṛti, and I Puruṣa“. This beautiful reference to Śiva/Śivā being both the wave and still water, both the hasty/active/rapid and yet calm and auspicious is described in Sukla Yajur Veda Vājasaneyi Saṃhitā 16.31. Hence, the Rishis ask Rudra to bestow that Anandam. [(Source link for detailed readers)](http://namahshivaya.net/darshana/)

Comment: "Śiva is often translated as the destroyer,"  - at least Monier Williams says: शिव mf(आ)n. (according to, Uṇ. i, 153 , fr. √1. शी, ‘in whom all things lie’; perhaps connected with √श्वि cf. शवस्, शिश्वि) auspicious, propitious, gracious, favourable, benign, kind, benevolent, friendly, dear (°वम् ind. kindly, tenderly), RV.  &c. &c. [ID=217497]

Comment: @SK Here is a good post: https://qr.ae/pvYxII